# Find all children's key by specific key in a deep nested array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, treeview

```
const data = [
  {
    title: '0-0',
    key: '0-0',
    children: [
      {
        title: '0-0-0',
        key: '0-0-0',
        children: [
          { title: '0-0-0-0', key: '0-0-0-0' },
          { title: '0-0-0-1', key: '0-0-0-1' },
          { title: '0-0-0-2', key: '0-0-0-2' },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: '0-0-1',
        key: '0-0-1',
        children: [
          { title: '0-0-1-0', key: '0-0-1-0' },
          { title: '0-0-1-1', key: '0-0-1-1' },
          { title: '0-0-1-2', key: '0-0-1-2' },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: '0-0-2',
        key: '0-0-2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '0-1',
    key: '0-1',
    children: [
      { title: '0-1-0-0', key: '0-1-0-0' },
      { title: '0-1-0-1', key: '0-1-0-1' },
      { title: '0-1-0-2', key: '0-1-0-2' },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '0-2',
    key: '0-2',
  },
];
```

How would I get an array of all values throughout all nests of this obj by the key of id.

For example

input: ["0-0-0"]

i wanna output like this

output: ["0-0-0", "0-0-0-0", "0-0-0-1", "0-0-0-2"]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJNGK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recursively loop over all the `children` and get the keys that *either* match one of the target keys *or* if any of their ancestors have matched one the target keys.

```js
const data = [
  {
    title: "0-0",
    key: "0-0",
    children: [
      {
        title: "0-0-0",
        key: "0-0-0",
        children: [
          { title: "0-0-0-0", key: "0-0-0-0" },
          { title: "0-0-0-1", key: "0-0-0-1" },
          { title: "0-0-0-2", key: "0-0-0-2" },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: "0-0-1",
        key: "0-0-1",
        children: [
          { title: "0-0-1-0", key: "0-0-1-0" },
          { title: "0-0-1-1", key: "0-0-1-1" },
          { title: "0-0-1-2", key: "0-0-1-2" },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: "0-0-2",
        key: "0-0-2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "0-1",
    key: "0-1",
    children: [
      { title: "0-1-0-0", key: "0-1-0-0" },
      { title: "0-1-0-1", key: "0-1-0-1" },
      { title: "0-1-0-2", key: "0-1-0-2" },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "0-2",
    key: "0-2",
  },
];

function getKeys(data, targetKeys) {
  const targetKeysSet = new Set(targetKeys);
  const outputKeys = [];
  function getKeysHelper(data, hasParentMatched = false) {
    data?.forEach((d) => {
      if (targetKeysSet.has(d.key) || hasParentMatched) {
        outputKeys.push(d.key);
        getKeysHelper(d.children, true);
      } else {
        getKeysHelper(d.children);
      }
    });
  }
  getKeysHelper(data);
  return outputKeys;
}

getKeys(data, ["0-0-0"]);
```

**Relevant documentations:**

- [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
- [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: can you check my another question? 
(i can't solve my problem so please help me)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72632278/find-parent-key-by-specific-key-in-a-deep-nested-array-object

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```js
const extractKeys = data => {
  const loop = (data, res) => {
  if(!data.children){
    return [...res, data.key]
  }
  return data.children.flatMap(d => loop(d, [...res, data.key]))
  }
  return [...new Set(loop(data, []))]
}


const findKeys = (data, keys) => data.flatMap(extractKeys).filter(k => keys.some(key => k.includes(key))) 



const data = [
  {
    title: '0-0',
    key: '0-0',
    children: [
      {
        title: '0-0-0',
        key: '0-0-0',
        children: [
          { title: '0-0-0-0', key: '0-0-0-0' },
          { title: '0-0-0-1', key: '0-0-0-1' },
          { title: '0-0-0-2', key: '0-0-0-2' },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: '0-0-1',
        key: '0-0-1',
        children: [
          { title: '0-0-1-0', key: '0-0-1-0' },
          { title: '0-0-1-1', key: '0-0-1-1' },
          { title: '0-0-1-2', key: '0-0-1-2' },
        ],
      },
      {
        title: '0-0-2',
        key: '0-0-2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '0-1',
    key: '0-1',
    children: [
      { title: '0-1-0-0', key: '0-1-0-0' },
      { title: '0-1-0-1', key: '0-1-0-1' },
      { title: '0-1-0-2', key: '0-1-0-2' },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: '0-2',
    key: '0-2',
  },
];

console.log(findKeys(data, ['0-0-0']))
```

Comment: thanks but input is array
like this ['0-0-0']